# Is it a jointly concave function of two variables?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have following function $f(x,y)=\min(y(1-x),xya)$ where $x\geq0,y\geq0,a\geq0$. Only $x$ and $y$ are the optimization variables. I want to ask is it a concave function of $(x,y)$? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not

if $a > 0$:
On the line $y =x$ function is $f(x,y)=\min(- x^2 + x,ax^2) $ so $f$ agrees with $a x^2$ near zero i.e., $f(x) = ax^2$ on small interval $[0 , \epsilon)$. which is not concave. Also it is clear that $f$ is not convex too.

**EDIT**

If $a  = 0$ then on the segment $\{ (1+t , 1-t) ~ : ~ 0 \leq t \leq1\} $

$f$ agrees with $t^2 -t$ which is not concave, clearly $f$ it is no convex too.

Comment: In my view it does not immediately follow that $f$ is concave when $a=0$. $y(1-x)$ is neither concave nor convex no matter what the sign of $x$ and $y$ are, so it is not clear why $\min\{y(1-x),0\}$ should be, either.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Oops you're right ! don't know why for some reasons felt the Hessian of $xy$ is positive on first quadrant ! in case $a= 0$ functions is not concave nor convex.

Comment: I cannot tell you how often people claim that about $xy$. _All_. _The_. _Time_.

Comment: @MichaelGrant even simple things can be confusing some times thats why I think its better to ask questions from knowledgeable people (may they be even the dumbest questions(just my opinion))